# Use my timer to get data in ViewModel (in kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-android-extensions

I have a `Foo` class, which wraps a `CountDownTimer`:

```
class Foo() {
    private val timer = object: CountDownTimer(2000, 1000) {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            // How MyViewModel could utilize this callback to get students in MyViewModel?
        }

        override fun onFinish() {
        }
    }

    fun start() {
        myTimer.start()
    }
}
```

In my ViewModel:

```
class MyViewModel constructor(repo: MyRepo): ViewModel() {
    fun getStudents(): LiveData<List<Student>> {
         // How to introduce my Foo class here to get student list every 2 seconds
         val studentList = liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
             val studentList = repo.getStudents()
             emit(studentList)
         }
         return studentList
    }
}
```

I want to refactor `MyViewModel` code to get students every 2 seconds by using `Foo` class, but I am not sure how to do that. Could someone please guide me?

Comment: You can invoke the data in your viewmodel and observe the result via liveData

Comment: @LiemVo Could you please show some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example

```
class Foo(private val viewModel: MyViewModel) {
    private val timer = object: CountDownTimer(2000, 1000) {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            viewModel.loadStudents()
        }

        override fun onFinish() {
        }
    }

    fun start() {
        timer.start()
    }
}
```

The `Foo` class holds an instance of `ViewModel` and can invoke the method `loadStudents` that will get the data from your repository

Here is the update of the ViewModel

```
class MyViewModel constructor(val repo: MyRepo): ViewModel() {

    private val _students = MutableLiveData<List<Student>>()
    val students: LiveData<List<Student>> // from your view (fragment or activity) observe this livedata
        get() = _students
    val foo = Foo(this)
    init {
        loadStudents()
    }

    fun loadStudents() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
            _students.postValue(repo.getStudents())
            foo.start()
        }
    }
}
```

The result responses from your `repo.getStudents` will be posted in the `liveData` that can be observed on your view.

Comment: I need to have different interval passed in to Foo for different data type inside ViewModel, how to do that?

Comment: You can call start again when the `repo.getStudents` complete

Comment: With this after start is called the repo.getStudents is called after interval seconds, how to make it so that when start is called it immediate get students after which it gets students every interval seconds?

Comment: @Leem Now it will get student when the ViewModel is started.